# dynamic DB connection on vc++ ; should need to read from config or ini instead of variable

Tags: visual-c++

existing code  ,need to change it as read connection string from  ini or config file -- vc++ 6.0

```
#define _NRPROD 1           //TEST ENVIRONMENT
```

## define _NRTEST 1           //TEST ENVIRONMENT

/** 
* This string is the connect string used to connect to the database.  If the database
* location changes, this string has to be updated.
*/

## if defined(_NRTEST)

```
static char  strDBConnect[128] = {"ODBC;Server=a1recurrent;DSN=nrtest1;UID=Model;PWD=model;"};
```

## elif defined(_NRPROD)

```
static char  strDBConnect[128] = {"ODBC;Server=(local);DSN=nrprod1;UID=Model;PWD=model;"};
```

## else   // default is development database

```
static char  strDBConnect[128] = {"ODBC;Server=a1recurrent;DSN=newdev;UID=Model;PWD=model;"};
```

## endif

Comment: Are you looking for `GetPrivateProfileString`? I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: i am new for vc++ .. the above code is from my project .. i need to move it into ini or config file.but the above code has written on header file

Comment: i would like to achieve dynamic db conection string on a existing  vc++ 6.0 application (like fetching connection string from config file).. i am experienced on vs .net  only ..

Comment: I'm not sure what more you expect to hear. If you are looking for someone to write the code for you, it's highly unlikely to happen here; I certainly am not interested in doing that. If you need to write C++, you would have to learn C++, or else hire someone who knows it. If you don't know how to use `GetPrivateProfileString` specifically, read the documentation - it's just one Google search away.

Comment: thank you igor tandetnik . 'GetPrivateProfileString' it is working fine on class files.. while i use the 'GetPrivateProfileString' on header file.it is throwing compile error ... actually i would like to keep that value on header file to use commonly.

Comment: What's the text of the error? Do you `#include <windows.h>` in that header before using the function? Why do you insist on using it in the header in the first place? You would normally have a variable declared in the header file (so you could use it elsewhere), but defined and initialized in some source file.

Comment: i included the <windows.h> even though GetPrivateProfileString function is not getenabling on my project header file ..(i am using windows XP and vc++ 6.0)